# Windows Phone - Consume Java Web Service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm a beginner in C#, my Visual Studio is the 2010, my version of Windows Phone 7 is researched on the internet and in this version of the command "async" only works Visual Studio 12 up.

You have any other alternative?

I can map the webservice with references service, but the return is always zero, but in Android works, what the error might be?

I changed the code to stay as he told me, but the error continues to occur:
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri: "webservices.com.br/"; site: "parameter1"). The expected elements are <{} parameter2>, <{} parameter1>
The following source code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage{
  wsServico.cadastroTo cadastroTo = null; 

  public MainPage(){
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    wsServico.TesteJavaWsClient ws = new wsServico.TesteJavaWsClient();
    ws.returnServicoAsync("A", "B");         
    ws.returnServicoCompleted += new EventHandler<wsServico.returnServicoCompletedEventArgs>(ws_returnServicoCompleted);

  }

  void ws_returnServicoCompleted(object sender, wsServico.returnServicoCompletedEventArgs e){
    cadastroTo = e.Result;
    textBox1.Text = cadastroTo.cadastroId.ToString();        

  }

}
```

Comment: Try adding this old [Async CTP via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncCTP/) and you'll be use Async/Await.

Comment: In the Nugget download page on the site, there is no version for Visual Studio 2010, what should I do ?

Comment: Here is [a post from MSDN on the Async CTP v3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2011/10/31/async-ctp-v3-installation/), try downloading the old installer and see if it works - also, do you have to use WP7, developing for WP8 or even Win10 mobile would make a lot more sense?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem otherwise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your textbox too early - before the web service call returns. After you fire off the web service call, you are immediately setting your textbox, which will be empty. You want to set the value in the `ws_returnServicoCompleted` method, after the web service has returned results.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    wsServico.TesteJavaWsClient ws = new wsServico.TesteJavaWsClient();
    ws.returnServicoAsync("A", "B");         
    ws.returnServicoCompleted += new EventHandler<wsServico.returnServicoCompletedEventArgs>(ws_returnServicoCompleted);
}

void ws_returnServicoCompleted(object sender,
   wsServico.returnServicoCompletedEventArgs e){
       cadastroTo = e.Result;
       cadastroTo.cadastroId.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please post your answer

Comment: I put the solution on my personal website link below: http://www.tidicas.com.br/?p=911